# Why is the whereIn query limiting to 10 on one page and not on the other?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I used [Quiver](https://pub.dev/packages/quiver) to handle the limit of 10 entries and it worked fine on one page. So I did exactly the same thing on another page fetching documents in the same collection but referring to a different field, the problem is that this second query is returning only 10 documents.

At first I did the exact same query on both pages. The first page query works normally on any page. Then I thought that the problem could be in the query itself, but as the only thing that is different in both is the name of the field I thought it could be something related to my indexes on the google cloud platform. So I recreated both indexes and it still didn't work. Honestly, I don't know what could be wrong.

I'll put both queries and a screenshot of my indexes, hopefully someone can understand ​​what may be happening.

**First Query** (working):

```
for (int i = 0; i < splitFollowing.length; i++) {
      QuerySnapshot querySnapshotFollowing = await db
          .collection('posts')
          .where('ownerId', whereIn: splitFollowing.elementAt(i))
          .orderBy('timestamp', descending: true)
          .limit(20)
          .getDocuments();

      return querySnapshotFollowing.documents.map((documentSnapshot) {
        return FeedPost.fromDocument(documentSnapshot);
      }).toList();
    }
```

**Second Query** (not working):

```
for (int i = 0; i < splitCollections.length; i++) {
      QuerySnapshot querySnapshotCollection = await db
          .collection('posts')
          .where('postId', whereIn: splitCollections.elementAt(i))
          .orderBy('timestamp', descending: true)
          .limit(20)
          .getDocuments();

      return querySnapshotCollection.documents.map((documentSnapshot) {
        return CollectionPost.fromDocument(documentSnapshot);
      }).toList();
    }
```

**Indexes**:
[image]

**Update**:

I was doing some tests and I found something. After deleting the second index (postId), I got this error in the terminal:

[image]

And as you can see in the print() I did, there are 11 items in the list but in the error message only 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're facing this problem, change your approach to Firebase Functions.